# HTTP Request result not visible

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Guys I am facing a problem in flutter web. I am following this tutorial
https://flutter-examples.com/flutter-online-user-login-using-php-mysql-api/
In this tutorial I learned how to make an app having login feature with PHP MySQL. I just copy paste all the code from the above link and it actually works same as given above in Android and ios perfectly but it doesn't work in flutter web. The problem in flutter web is, when I click on the login button the spinner only rotates and doesn't return anything. If the credentials are wrong then it must throw an error by showing alert dialog and if the password is right then it must navigates to profile screen which is not happening in flutter web. And also it is not throwing any kind of error.

Currently I am in latest beta channel

Guys please help me

Comment: Check Status code of HTTP request that you are doing

Comment: try also to print the body of response using print( respone.body);

Answer (score 0):

Check for status code and try to use print() to see status code and its body

```
  // Starting Web API Call.
  var response = await http.post(url, body: json.encode(data));
    if(response.status==200)
  var message = jsonDecode(response.body);
else{
throw Exception("${response.body}:body");
}
```

Comment: I've added the following code and now it is throwing an exception which is given below Error: XMLHttpRequest error.